# A SDE that "forgets" its input

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be the Wiener process.

Consider the coupled SDE
$$ dX_t = - X_t dt + \sqrt{2} dW_t$$
$$ d\bar W_t = -\sqrt{2} X_t dt + dW_t$$

with initial conditions $\bar W_0 = 0$ and $X_0 \sim N(0, 1)$.
The symbol $\bar W$ is arbitrary and I could have labeled the second process $dY_t = -\sqrt{2} X_t + dW_t$, but it will be apparent later why this symbol was chosen.

Under these conditions, $X$ is a stationary Ornstein Uhlenbeck process. What's interesting is that $\bar W$ seems to be a standard Wiener process, driven by both $W$ and $X$. Even more, $X_t$ seems to be independent of $\bar W_s$ for $s \le t$ so in some way, $\bar W$ remembers nothing about $X$, even though $X$ enters into its SDE.

Is there a way to (easily) prove this? The above facts can be justified if one can show uniqueness of the solution to the associated Fokker-Planck equation, but I haven't been able to prove that. Instead, I have some computer simulations.

**Sample Paths of W**
These are just sample paths of the Wiener process. Nothing too surprising here.
[image: Sample Paths of W]

**Sample Paths of X**
These show that, indeed, $X$ is the stationary Ornstein Uhlenbeck process.
[image: Sample Paths of X]

**Sample Paths of $\bar W$**
Here is a surprise. These paths look like they follow a Wiener process.
[image: Sample Paths of bar W]

Here are plots of the sample path variances of $W$ and $\bar W$, where the horizontal axis is time, and the vertical axis is the variance of all sample paths. This is is further evidence that $\bar W$ is also a Wiener process.
[image: sample path variances]

However, $W$ is correlated with $X$, since it is the driving process behind $X$. Weirdly, $\bar W$ is uncorrelated with $X$.

[image: correlation plots]

Comment: I suggest that you use $Y_t$ instead of $\bar{W}_t$ to make the question clearer. Besides, in the two first equations, it should be 
$$ dX_t = - X_t dt + \sqrt{2} dW_t$$
$$ d Y_t = -\sqrt{2} X_t dt + dW_t$$

Comment: @NN2 Thanks for the correction. I didn't want to remake some of the charts so I added a note about the label $\bar W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to deduce the closed-form expression of the OU process $X_t$:
$$X_t = X_0 e^{-t} + \sqrt{2}\int_0^t e^{s-t}dW_s \tag{1}$$
and we observe that
$$d\bar{W}_t = dW_t -\sqrt{2}X_t dt =dW_t +\sqrt{2}  \left(dX_t - \sqrt{2} dW_t  \right) = \sqrt{2}dX_t-dW_t$$
then, we deduce the closed-form expression of $\bar{W}_t$
$$\implies \bar{W}_t =\sqrt{2}(X_t - X_0)-W_t = \sqrt{2}X_0(e^{-t}-1)+\int_0^t\left(2e^{s-t} - 1  \right)dW_s \tag{2}$$

---

The stochastic integral of $(2)$ follow a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}\left(  0, \int_0^t(2e^{s-t}-1)^2 ds\right)$ and is independent to $X_0$, then, $\bar{W}_t$ follows also a normal distribution
$$\bar{W}_t   \sim  \mathcal{N}\left(  0,2(e^{-t}-1)^2+ \int_0^t(2e^{s-t}-1)^2 ds\right) = \mathcal{N}\left(  0,t\right)$$
The process $(\bar{W}_t)_t$ is then a standard Wiener process.

---

For the correlation between $X_t$ and $\bar{W}_s$ for $s \le t$, as $X_t$ and $\bar{W}_s$ follows both normal distributions, the dependence of $(X_t,\bar{W}_s)$ can be check by calculating the covariance $\mathbb{E}(X_t\bar{W}_s)$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X_t\bar{W}_s) &= \mathbb{E} \left(\left(X_0 e^{-t} + \sqrt{2}\int_0^t e^{u-t}dW_u \right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{2}X_0(e^{-s}-1)+\int_0^s\left(2e^{u-s} - 1  \right)dW_u \right) \right)\\
&=\sqrt{2}e^{-t}(e^{-s}-1)\mathbb{E} \left(X_0^2 \right)+ \mathbb{E} \left(\left( \sqrt{2}\int_0^t e^{u-t}dW_u \right)\cdot\left(\int_0^s\left(2e^{u-s} - 1  \right)dW_u \right) \right)\\
&=\sqrt{2}e^{-t}(e^{-s}-1) + \sqrt{2} \mathbb{E} \left(\left( \int_0^\color{red}{s} e^{u-t}dW_u \right)\cdot\left(\int_0^s\left(2e^{u-s} - 1  \right)dW_u \right) \right)\\
&=\sqrt{2}e^{-t}(e^{-s}-1) + \sqrt{2} e^{-s - t} (-1 + e^s)\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

The covariance is  null, we deduce that $(X_t,\bar{W}_s)$ is uncorrelated.

Comment: Incredible! If you are interested, your calculations show a "counterexample" to theorem 3.10 here https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82826666.pdf

This theorem is currently used applied towards "diffusion models" which are currently popular in the machine learning world (e.g the Stable Diffusion image generator). Its failure in such a simple case casts doubt on the applicability of this theorem in general.

Comment: @Mark I looked quickly at the paper you had cited. Does $X_0$ follow a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, are these parameters $f(X_t, t), g(X_t,t)$ and in particular the parameter $\frac{1}{p(X_t, t} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (p(X_t,t) g (X_t,t))$ well calculated? Could you give me the function $p(X_t,t)$?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. These parameters are specified in $(3.3)$ and are supposed to be generic drift-diffusion parameters for the process $X$. For our case, $X$ is the OU process with $f(X_t, t) = -X_t$, $g(X_t, t) = \sqrt{2}$. $X_0$ is allowed to be any "almost-surely bounded" (pg 316) which is not satisfied here, but I don't think his theorem uses the boundedness assumption.

The function $p(X_t,t)$ is the distribution of $X$ at time $t$. So for us, it is simply $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp(-x_t^2/2)$ since we have the stationary distribution.

Comment: The reason I put "counter-example" in quotes previously is that the theorem is certainly true, given the assumption of unique solvability of the associated Kolmogorov equations. However, practitioners will ignore technicalities, so it's important to see if the theorem holds at least for a simple class of examples for pragmatic purposes.

Comment: @Mark If $p(x,t)$ is the density function at $(x,t)$ of the process $X_t$, I think it must be different than what you wrote (even if $X_t$ does really follow the normal distribution), because the variance of $X_t$ is not $1$ but some kind of  $2 (\int_0^t e^{s-t} ds)^2 + e^{-2t}$. Hence, you should have this variance in the denominator (inside the square root, with $2\pi$) and in the exponent.

Comment: In your expression, the square should go on the inside. Hence we have $2(\int_0^t(e^{s - t})^2 ds) + e^{-2t} = 1$. This also follows from the fact the stationary distribution of $X_t$ is $N(0,1)$ and the initial distribution is also $N(0,1)$, and $X_t$ is the OU process.

Comment: @Mark Ah, you are right about the variance of $X_t$. And I think as it's less likely possible that the theorem is wrong, then either my calculation contains errors, either there is at least a parameter is not correctly calculated.

Comment: Hmm is your expression after equation (2) alright? The first term needs a sqrt 2 and the constant inside the integrand needs to be half instead of one I think

Comment: @Mark I corrected the error. The result is now as expected.

Comment: So the theorem is saved! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on NN2's answer.

A. To verify the closed form $(1)$ $ X_t  = X_0 e^{-t} + \int_0^t \sqrt{2} e^{s-t}\, dW_s$ from NN2's answer:

Set $Y_t = e^{t} X_t$. Setting $y(x, t) = x e^t$, we have by the Ito Lemma $dY_t = \left[\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}|_{(X_t, t)}  - X_t \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}|_{(X_t, t)} + \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}|_{(X_t, t)}\right]dt + \sqrt{2} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}|_{(X_t, t)} dW_t$.
Hence $dY_t = \sqrt{2} e^t\, dW_t$. So $Y_t - Y_0 = e^t X_t - X_0 = \int_0^t \sqrt{2} e^s\, dW_s$.

B. To verify Wiener-ness of $\bar W$ we also need to talk about the increments  $\bar W_{t + \Delta t} - \bar W_t$. But these are distributed as $N(0, \Delta t)$ appealing to the $t=0$ case and that $X$ is stationary.